# Get selected row index and column index from radgrid

Tags: telerik-grid

I'm using telerik:radgrid. I'm using the OnItemCommand event handler for the grid. I am able to get the rowindex but i can't seem to find anything for columnIndex.

I am open to 2 methods to reach this answer. i'd like to either get the value of the cell clicked in codebehind (in the onItemCommand) or i can do the same thing if i can get the selectedColumnIndex.

i've seen javascript solutions but i'd like to attempt to use the eventHandler in codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a way to get Selected Row Index and pass it to another grid and here is what I ended up doing:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid2.SelectedIndexes.Clear();
    RadGrid2.SelectedIndexes.Add(e.Item.ItemIndex);
}
```

It might help those looking to get RowIndex

Answer (score 0):

you can do this...

```
If (radgrid.MasterTableView.Items.Count > 0){
    string strText = radgrid.MasterTableView.Items[rowIndex][columnIndex].Text();
}
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation as it might help a lot the author

Comment: Where do you get rowIndex and columnIndex's values?
I have this bit of code, and columnIndex is undefined.... I'm attempting to locate where this value can be drilled out. 
    protected void rgData_OnItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "RowClick":
                RadGrid radgrid = sender as RadGrid;
                if (radgrid.MasterTableView.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    string strText = radgrid.MasterTableView.Items[rowIndex][columnIndex].Text();
                }